# How to get the java application control HWND

Tags: java, windows

how can I get/fetch the handle (HWND) of a control(e.g. JBUtton.. etc) from java application created from netbeans? Using Window Detective, all i can get is SunAWTFrame and SunAWTToolkit. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These controls are non-windowed and so do not have a window handle. It is simply not possible to do what you ask.

Comment: On top of that in case of the JButton etc. they're controls rendered by Java itself, not the operating system.

Comment: @Gimby Ultimately the Java code that renders the controls will call Win32 API functions, at least on Windows of course. The key is that this GUI framework does not use windowed controls.

Comment: Only win32 API drawing calls (and maybe even not that if hardware rendering is used and/or a specific look & feel is configured). But Swing components do not make use of the OS API at all, they're lightweight.

Comment: @Gimby Yes, I'm referring to Win32 gdi functions.